# how use how listener div

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I want to use @hostListner on div to execute a method when div is loaded:

```
<div id="content">
<router-outlet ></router-outlet>
</div>
```

in my app.ts I do:

```
  @HostListener('window:load',['$event'])
  onPageLoad(event: Event) {
     console.log('loaded',event); }
```

I don't want how listener is called on `'window:load'`. I want call somethink like this

```
 @HostListener('content:load',['$event'])
  onPageLoad(event: Event) {
     console.log('loaded',event); }
```

I don't know if I can do this. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Aren't you taking Angular's lifecycle hooks into consideration? ngAfterViewInit, ngOnInit??